# How to add Active Directory users as sudoers

Tags: sudo, configuration, active-directory

I'm following this [article](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-active-directory-integration-with-centrify-directcontrol-express-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot.html#more-12690). What I've done:

- I can connect to Active Directory
- I can login to the Active Directory

Now what I'm looking for is a way to make any active directory user a sudoer. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Active Directory 2008r2

Answer (score 0):

For sudoers file:

In a terminal type:

```
sudo visudo
```

and got to line

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

add your domain like this:

```
%domain\\domain^Users ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

but I advice you to use the [LikewiseOpen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen)

Comment: Better edit /etc/sudoers with `visudo`, it checks if the syntax is right before saving.

Comment: any way i used to nano .

Comment: @ahmedsami that's okay. You can set the EDITOR environment variable to nano. Then commands like visudo will use that editor.